# REGEX - How can I select/mark 3 works delimited by tabs on a consecutive lines?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

Happy New Year !

I have a problem. I don’t know how to marks\select some words delimited by tabs on a consecutive lines: Recent, Coments and Tags

please see this print screen:

[image: https://snag.gy/ZXNxJR.jpg]

I can easy to put `|` sign, like: `Recent|Comments|Tags` but this will select all the words in the files that repeats, and I want only those 3 on those lines.

What I want is to make a regex, to remove all text before those 3 words, and another regex to remove everything after those 3 words.

I try something like this `((?s)((^.*)^.*Recente.*$|^.*Coments.*$|^.*Tags.*^))(.*$)`but is not very good. And I have to pay atention, because those words can repeated in the text files, so I have to select\mark exactly those 3, on that 3 consecutive line (that doesn't have any other words on it)

Comment: Did you try `Recent\s+Comments\s+Tags`? See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8I25Sl/1). --- Instead of removing before/after text, just keep what you find. Same result.

Comment: sorry, not working in notepad++ your regex formula. In fact, regex101 is not very compatible with many editors.

Comment: You might try `^[\s\S]*?^(\h+Recente\R\h+Coments\R\h+Tags)$[\s\S]*` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: doesn't work at my place

Comment: Does it mean there are horizontal spaces after these words? Please provide the text sample in the question body. It is not possible to help with text parsing when image only is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned in a comment that you want to do this in **Notepad++** *(a fact that should have been mentioned in the question text)*, and since the screenshot shows a single space after the first two words, you might try this regular expression:

```
.*\n([ \t]+Recente\s+Coments\s+Tags).*
```

It will select everything, but capture the 3 words including whitespace between them and whitespace preceding first word on same line.

If you then replace with `$1`, everything not in the capture group will be removed.

[image]

Actually, the spaces after the first two words don't matter to this regex.

Comment: but how can I delete just everything before those 3 words?

Comment: Remove the `.*` at the end of the regex.

Comment: super ! And if I want to delete also those 3 line with that words , I will leave empty the "Replace with" section.

I modify a little bit your regex, so to not check the **.match newline**

Search `(?s).*\n([ \t]+Recente\s+Coments\s+Tags)`
Replace by: `Leave empty`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this in perl:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while(m/((\s|\t)+)Recent\n\1Comments\n\1Tags/g){print "$&\n";}' /path/to/file
```

To breakdown:

- Start with 1 or more tab characters (first capture group)
- Then "Recent" followed by new line
- Capture group, Comments and new line
- Capture group, Tags

By the way, is "tab" really tab or multiple consecutive whitespaces (\s+)?

Comment: I added that (it can be white space or tab). Well I don't know much either, however, perl is more powerful than similar tools like sed when it comes to regex.